# How can I make my AMP redundant?

Tags: reactjs, amp-html, google-amp

*I have made a static HTML page using the AMP boilerplate which contains details of a fruit product say apple, so my URL looks like
`www.xyz.com/apple`

The page contains a simple `<amp-carousel>` and some data with `src` relevant to apple.(product in route) Which contains the title 'Apple', 3 images inside `<amp-img>` of `<amp-carousel>`, and an `<amp-list>` with `src` depending upon URL route/path.

Lets say I have other products whose details I want to show by changing route path to `www.xyz.com/orange`, `www.xyz.com/pears`, `www.xyz.com/grapes` etc.

SupposeI want to keep it dynamic depending upon the URL, say for `www.xyz.com/orange`, my static page would now contain similar information, but relevant to URL path - ie. `orange`/`pears`/`grapes`

**As the different product contains the different title, different number of images for `amp-list`, `amp-carousel` or any simple list, how can I make my content dynamic for updated path in URL using ReactJS/ES6 syntax.**

Also, provide any information about data flow/lifecycle methods for AMP pages before HTML is made on the server(which I assume I am missing).

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can't use ReactJS or ES6 in an AMP page as stated in the AMP spec [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec).

What you're trying to do will require a fairly basic set up on the backend that'll take the path to determine what data to use to build an AMP page.